Hook before DB connection is made
This is not a question but a post that needs suggestion -
In WP there should be a hook that should fire before any DB connection is made.
Using this hook we can filter some request which come to our website as bad bot or brute force attack.
Example - If someone tries to brute force our login pages via some script, even if the request has invalid username or password, the attack will use many resources as it will make DB connection and few default queries will be running before making authentication check.
If there would be some hook that that fires before DB connection then there we can see if username and password is present and a hidden field in login ( will add a hidden field just to validate if value matches when trying to login ) . We can check in brute force attack that hidden field in not present then directly block the request.
As of now I have done it by adding on the top of wp-config.php file and it is not making any DB connection but just wanted to see it there would be an hook for this it would be great.

This seems like something that belongs on Core Trac as a feature suggestion.

The problem with having a "hook" is that the add_action() function would not be defined that early so WordPress would have to be recoded so that the function is available much earlier.
Also to use an action hook you would need to add your code inside a theme or a plugin. WordPress must make database requests in order to load themes and plugins. So the code that hooks into this action would have to be added inside an MU plugin and again WordPress would need to be re-coded so that MU plugins load earlier.
I highly doubt WordPress would ever update to support this.
Bots, Brute Force attacks, DDoS...etc. This should all be managed server-side via your website's firewall. Not via PHP.
